# Spatial merge in R returns "non-unique matches detected" even though data has unique value

Tags: r, merge, spatial

I am trying to merge a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with a normal data frame.

The SpatialPolygonDataFrame looks as follows:

```
    check1    LargeSpatialDataFrame
    ......@data:'data.frame' : 206 obs
    $latitude : num 
    $longitude: num
    $name1 : int
```

The normal dataframe looks as follows:

```
    Val1    name1         
    18262   662     
    55484   532    
    20859   525
```

The DataFrame has 210 unique "name1" value and the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame has 206 unique "name1" value.

When I run the below command I get the following "Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected"

```
    sp::merge(check1,groupdma,by.x="dma",by.y="dma_number",all=TRUE,duplicateGeoms=FALSE)
```

How do I fix this error? My main aim is to create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that I can pass to the leaflet function to create a chloropeth map. I have tried the link [here](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/10/14/manipulating-and-mapping-us-census-data-in-r-using-the-acs-tigris-and-leaflet-packages-3/), but the area of my polygons always came out to be 0. Hence I am trying to use sp::merge in order to avoid the steps given in the link.

The dataframe and the spatialdataframe, both do not have duplicate id values.

Comment: I had a similar question, but I haven't figured out an answer yet. Did you notice that you're doing a one-to-many join: "Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected"? I think this is the cause of the problem. I searched a little bit online for one-to-many joins in R, but had no luck. As an aside, this question might have had better luck on the GIS version of stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Change duplicateGeoms=FALSE to duplicateGeoms=TRUE